# Passing function as class template argument

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

Without knowing a function's type, I am declaring its pointer with below technique and initializing a function pointer.

```
template<typename T>
struct Declare { typedef T Type; }; // for declaring any func ptr

void fun () {}

int main ()
{
  Declare<fun>::Type pf = &fun;  // can't use C++0x 'auto'
}
```

However, it gives compile error as, `error: expected a type, got ‘fun’`. Though the type of any method is known at compile time. **Is it invalid to pass a function into a class `template` as above ?**

[Note: replacing `fun` with `void (*)()` works fine. But that's not what want.]

Comment: Can you use C++0x other features (not auto)?

Comment: @Nawaz, not as of now, because I don't have the updated compiler available. Also, I can't rely on when new standard releases. But will be curious to know just for sake of knowledge, if you have any other way (even though in C++0x); I was guessing for variadic tempates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it invalid to pass a function into a class template as above?

Yes. Because what you, in other words, want the compiler to deduce the *type* parameter for the class template, which simply not possible in C++. Recall that `fun` itself isn't a *type*, its a *value* of type `void (*)()`. But your class template expects type, not value. That's why it wouldn't work.

Type deduction is possible with functions only, that means even with the constructor of class. So if you write a templated constructor, and then you can write this:

```
Declare obj(&fun);
```

Here the type of the function is known as long as you're in constructor, once you exist from it, you lost the information. So what you probably need is : define a class, say, `AbstractFunctor` (possibly class template) and derived from it defining an another class say `template<Fun fun> struct Functor`. Then you can create an instance of `Functor` which can remember the function type forever, and store the instance in `AbstractFunctor*` as a member data of `Declare`.

But I think, even in this way, the type cannot be used as `Declare::Type` or `Declare::AbstractFunctor::Type`, simply because the *type* is stored in an *instance* of the class; only the instance knows the *type*. So the getting type using syntax like `A::Type` is out of the question. And you cannot get type using syntax `instance.Type` either. All you can do is : call the function, using the *instance*, like a functor.

---

EDIT:

If you're allowed to use C++0x's other features (excluding auto), then the problem has a trivial solution:

```
Declare<decltype(&fun)>::Type pf = &fun;  
pf(); //call the function
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/

But then, you don't need even `Declare`, as you can do this instead:

```
decltype(&fun) pf = &fun; 
pf(); //call the function
```

Comment: I have already mentioned that in my note. And if that is the case, why I will go for template wrapper ? I can directly declare it. The idea is to declare a variable without knowing function type.

Comment: In your edited answer as you said, I tried for using a `function template`, but I am not able to get the type out of the function by anyway. I think, it may not be possible for current standard.

Comment: by the way your first answer should be YES (as I am asking for is it invalid ?) ...  :)

Comment: @iammilind: Yeah.. that should be Yes. Also see the edit in the last para.

Comment: @iammilind: See the EDIT for C++0x solution.

Comment: @Nawaz: Doesn't even need the `Declare` struct then anymore, as that's just a simple forward. :P

Answer (score 5):

> Is it invalid to pass a function into a class template as above ?

Totally yes, you're mixing up type and non-type parameters.
`fun` is a **non-type** argument, it's an address of a function, like an arbitary number `0x12345678`.
`typename T` is a **type** parameter. You can only pass it types, like `int`,`MyClass`, `double (*)(std::string)`, `void (MyClass::*)()`.
You'll just have to life with the fact, that you need compiler support for that stuff or some really ugly trickery to deduce the type.
If you're in for the trickery, there's [`Boost.Typeof`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/typeof.html) for non-C++0x coder like you. It also provides a stand-in for `auto` with `BOOST_AUTO`, but that is only a short way for writing `BOOST_TYPEOF`:

```
int hello(){ return 42; }
BOOST_AUTO(var1,hello()); // type of var1 == int
BOOST_TYPEOF(hello()) var2 = hello(); // same
```

The problem? You need to help it for every user-defined type you have. See [this Ideone example](http://ideone.com/O2Dpl).

---

Now, most of the time I don't think you need Boost.Typeof. Why? Because if you use a function, you of course need to know the signature, how would you pass the correct arguments otherwise? Or use the return type in a correct way?
The other times are the usage in templates anyways. If you declare a function pointer like `auto fptr = &func`, then you have the knowledge, that `func` exists, aka you know its signature and type. For when you don't know that `func` exists, you need it passed to you anyways, preferably in a template:

```
template<class FPtr>
void myfunc(FPtr otherfunc){
  // use otherfunc
}
```

And with a template you have the knowledge of that functions type again.

Comment: @iammilind: Edited again with a little rationale as to why you shouldn't need Boost.Typeof for anything else than convenience.

Comment: `Boost.Typeof` may not work with all compilers, as its implementation depends on compiler's extension; in case of GCC, it uses GCC's extension `typeof` internally.

Comment: @Nawaz: Correct, if possible Boost.Typeof uses the native solutions, which is a good point if you aim for cross-plattform/-compiler compatability without ugly #ifdef branches, as Boost already does that. And if a native solution isn't existant on a target compiler, it emulates it just fine.

Comment: @Xeo, Nawaz is correct for normal `typeof`; however, I was not bothered about any "typeof". Just wanted to know that what can be the reason of not accepting function as template type inside `class`, which I got it from your first few lines. Rest of your answer I din't bother. :)

Comment: @Xeo: No, if the compiler doesn't provide extension, then it simply doesn't work :D

Comment: @iammilind: In that case, my first answer (which I erased) was correct, as in that I had explained why that wouldn't work. But you gave me downvote instead (I guess) :D

Comment: @iammilind: Anyway, I again added few words in my first para. :D

Comment: I down voted because, you said the same thing which I already had mentioned in the question.